# Generate backup on new schema iterating over certain tables - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a list of table names from `sys.tables` that looks like this:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE 'ETL%'
```

I want to move to a new schema (kinda like a backup) and I was thinking of using something like the following query being `@table_name` the current item from the list:

```
SELECT *
INTO [historic].[@table_name]
FROM @table_name
```

However I cannot seem to sort out how I can make this kind of iterator.

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL. Also, have you looked at the `alter schema` documentation? You can `transfer` an object to a new schema.

Comment: @Stu In this case, using `transfer` will just change the schema, but I need to create a copy. Useful clause nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably only going to perform this once, you can use the following example query to construct the SQL statements needed, you can copy and paste into an SSMS window to use.

```
select Concat(
  'select * ',
  'into [historic].', QuoteName(name),
  ' from ', QuoteName(name), ';'
)
from sys.tables
where name like 'ETL%' and Schema_Name(schema_id) = 'dbo';
```